# Not to destroy current activity on back button is pressed

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activities, A and B. I have a button in A,when pressed starts a new intent to B.
However whenever I press the back button while in B, than click the button again is restarts Activity.I do not want to do that,I want it to resume Activity B.
Actually I am doing some networking in Activity B and I want to save unless the user wants to refresh.
How can I do it? Thanks in advance

Comment: put code in your question , what is the method you are using?! have u tried
    onResume() ?

Comment: You mean, you want to disable the Back button?

Comment: don't call finish() while you are starting activity B

Comment: When user is in ActivityB and uses BACK, what should happen? Should it go back to ActivityA? If so, what should happen with the existing instance of ActivityB? You say it needs to stay around. Normally, pressing BACK means that you want to finish (exit, end) the current activity and return to the previous one.

Answer (score 25):

Use

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Hope, It must help you

Comment: you saved my day. Thanks .its working like the charm

Comment: and what i can do if i want to go back again to the back activity ?

Comment: you are a lifesaver Thx.

Comment: 9 years later you made my day

Answer (score 1):

You need to Overrider the

> onBackPressed

method  and start there the activity like this:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, activityA.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQ);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like you need to rethink your architecture. You say:

> Actually I am doing some networking in Activity B and I want to save
>   unless the user wants to refresh.

If this is the case, you probably don't want to do your networking in ActivityB. Maybe you should start a `Service` from ActivityB to do the networking. The service and the activity can communicate with each other so that the activity can keep the user up-to-date about the state of the networking. If the user presses BACK in ActivityB, it can finish (as usual) and return to ActivityA. In this case, the Service is still managing the networking. When the user again starts ActivityB (from ActivityA), the new instance of ActivityB can communicate with the service to see if there is any networking going on, and if so it can get the current status of that networking or start it or stop it or whatever.

Comment: Not really :-( I would need to see what you've already got and that goes beyond the scope of this Q&A forum. That becomes software consulting by the hour ;-) Look around at tutorials and sample code that performs network I/O in a background thread. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'm too late but I had a similar problem.

I had two activities A,B and a next button in A.

Whenever I tried to do: A->press next button ->B->press back button->A->press next button->B, B screen got destroyed when I pressed the back button. So when I came back to B for the second time it was a newly created B (all the information I had put in was gone).

So it was like A->B->A->new B when I just wanted to go back to the original B! :(

So what I did was, in activity B, I overrode the onBackPressed() function so it doesn't destroy the activity. I also set the flag so that if there is a A activity already running, it would just pull it up to the front instead of creating a new A activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Then, for the onclicklistener function for the next button in activity A, I set the flags similarly.

```
public void onClickNextbutton(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityB.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```